# Convert Audio output signal to a switch

Tags: audio, signal

How could I evaluate the signals from the audio input so that it acts as a switch to turn on my Bluetooth Speaker?

Comment: What kind of signals?

Comment: Audio Signals which is coming into the Audio In of Bluetooth Speaker

Comment: If it's a normal stereo socket, these usually have additional pin which gets shorted or opened when the jack is inserted. That might be the easiest choice.

Answer (score 0):

LM311 comparator. Or any modern similar chip. LM311 has open collector and emitter on its output transistor so is easy to use with any power supply. http://www.ti.com/product/LM311